# How to center position of specific TreeView node?

Tags: delphi, treeview

When i open form with TTreeView, i fill it in with some data and select some node. But i need to make selected node to be visible in center of the control (when possible of course). I can't find how to do it with standard TTreeView component. 
Any ideas ?

Comment: Wouldn't be enough for you to ensure it visible by [`MakeVisible`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TTreeNode.MakeVisible) ? What you want requires to calculate the distance to scroll and scrolling by yourself.

Comment: @TLama - I am using Delphi XE3 and when i select node it became visible, but it looks not very good, because user need to see some context (items below and above of selected).

Comment: Well, so then get the node bounds (`DisplayRect(False)`), calculate its distance to the position to be centered and scroll the control. That's the only way I can think of.

Comment: @TLama - It seems to be what i need (i missed DisplayRect when was looking for solution). Will check it tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can find to scroll a TreeView is to send it a `WM_VSCROLL` with a value of `SB_LINEDOWN`/`SB_LINEUP`. For some reason the control does not seem to respond to a scroll value of `SB_THUMBPOSITION`, like for instance a rich edit does. For this reason, the below try, centers a node *more or less* by sending the control a bunch of line scroll messages. Try and see for yourself if it suits your needs.

```
var
  DR, CR: TRect;
  ScrollPx, ScrollLines, i: Integer;
begin
  if Assigned(TreeView1.Selected) then begin

    // calculate how many *pixels* should we scroll
    DR := TreeView1.Selected.DisplayRect(False);
    CR := TreeView1.ClientRect;
    ScrollPx := - Round((CR.Bottom / 2) - DR.Top - ((DR.Bottom - DR.Top) / 2));

    // how many lines does it correspond to
    ScrollLines := ScrollPx div TreeView_GetItemHeight(TreeView1.Handle);

    // scroll that many lines
    if ScrollLines > 0 then
      for i := 1 to ScrollLines do
        TreeView1.Perform(WM_VSCROLL, MakeWParam(SB_LINEDOWN, 0), 0)
    else if ScrollLines < 0 then
      for i := ScrollLines to -1 do
        TreeView1.Perform(WM_VSCROLL, MakeWParam(SB_LINEUP, 0), 0);
  end;
```

Comment: I'm still wondering if there's a definitive answer on how to scroll any window control (having scrollbars) by pixels. I was able at most to move the content of a window (by `ScrollWindowEx` function), but it was not ever persistent. When the control was invalidated, the window content *moved* back and I never find out how to move the scrolbars accordingly. Maybe I should have spend more time on it. [+1]

Comment: @TLama - I never quite figured out what `ScrollWindow[Ex]` is good for. I've always assumed it doesn't really scroll anything but it's a shortcut for painting an offset region of your own scrolling control, burden of painting the invalidated part still resting on you. It doesn't work with ready-made controls because they paint their original appearance as soon as they get a chance. I may be very wrong though.. Thanks for the vote. :)

Comment: I can't get the code above to compile in Delphi 7.   TreeView_GetItemHeight is undefined, as is TreeView1.GetItemHeight.  Any suggestions, @SertacAkyuz?

Comment: @Tom - Include 'commctrl' in uses clause.